# Extract only certain html text

Tags: c#, html, regex, strip

Using Regex in C# I am able to convert this HTML text to plaintext but I'm trying to get only the email portion of the text. Is it possible to only get the email body of this HTML and not the greeting or sign off part?

```
<p style="font-size: 11pt;font-family: Times;">December 28, 2018</p>
    <p style="font-size: 11pt;font-family: Times;">Dear Lisa,</p>
    <p style="font-size: 11pt;font-family: Times;"> I would love to grab coffee with you!<br clear="none">When does that work? </p><p style="font-size: 11pt;font-family: Times;">Best Regards,</p>
```

Comment: There are are lots of follow up questions here. What constitutes the email body? Based on your example, it could be all `<p>` tags except the first, second and last. What if the email doesn't start with a greeting? You'll need to come up with some programmatic rules that define where the body is, and then try to implement those.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [HTML Agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) for doing things with Html. You can probably do this with HTML Agility Pack:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("<p style=\"font - size: 11pt; font - family: Times; \">December 28, 2018</p><p style = \"font-size: 11pt;font-family: Times;\" > Dear Lisa,</ p >" +
                     "<p style=\"font-size: 11pt;font-family: Times;\"> I would love to grab coffee with you!<br clear = \"none\"> When does that work ? </ p >< p style = \"font-size: 11pt;font-family: Times;\" > Best Regards,</ p >");

foreach (var nodeData in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(nodeData.InnerText);
}
```

Prints:

```
December 28, 2018

 Dear Lisa,

 I would love to grab coffee with you!

 When does that work ?

 Best Regards,
```

Comment: Could I just extract the `I would love to grab coffee with you! When does that work ?` part of the email?

Comment: need a way to differentiate "I would love to grab coffee with you!" from the rest. Can it come with a <p class="bodyEmail"> or the body doesnt contains a ','